# Can I use any GPU with a given set of hardware (CPU, RAM, etc.)?

Tags: gpu, desktop-computer, hardware-rec

I'm thinking of upgrading my GPU (an AMD Radeon R7 200 Series) with something more modern to be able to play videogames and render videos faster. The thing is that I'm not planning on changing my whole setup but just the GPU.

What I'm not sure about is if I can just buy any GPU I want and the computer will work alright, or if there are just some GPUs that can fit with the rest of the components I currently have. I suspect the power supply should be changed because a more powerful GPU would consume more power, but what about the other elements (CPU, motherboard, RAM, the case itself)? Are there any constrains regarding these?

My current hardware is composed of:

- Motherboard: ASUS A55M-A
- CPU: AMD A10-5800K
- RAM: 8GB DDR3

Comment: Add in this post more information like the entire build hardware list.

Comment: @jluizsouzadev Done!

Comment: I'd call this off topic. It should be posted at hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally put any GPU in a system provided the PCIe (or AGP for ancient systems) supports it.  In the case of the [ASUS A55M-A](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/A55MA/specifications/) it has 1xPCIe 2.0x16 slot that you can use and is designed for this purpose.